# How to add places parameter in google map API URL to fetch specific type of location for auto-complete

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete, customplaces

I'm trying to implement a autocomplete search `input` bar for auto-completing the results of searching colleges and university in my `React` app.

my code is as per the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import PlacesAutocomplete from "react-places-autocomplete";

export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { address: '' };
  }

  handleChange = address => {
    this.setState({ address });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      <PlacesAutocomplete
      value={this.state.address}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      onSelect={this.handleSelect}
      // searchOptions={searchOptions}
      shouldFetchSuggestions={this.state.address.length > 3}

    >
      {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => (
        <div >


          <input maxLength="50" className="typo"{...getInputProps({ placeholder: "Search Your College" })} />

          <div>
            {loading ? <div>...loading</div> : null}

            {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
              const style = {
                backgroundColor: suggestion.active ? "#41b6e6" : "",
              };
              return (

                <div className="suggestion"  {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, { style })}>
                  {suggestion.description}
                </div>

              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </PlacesAutocomplete>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

and obviously the `<script>` tag in index.html

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

[According to The gmaps docs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests), in order to only get selective results from these [types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types): `school`,`university`,`secondary-school` and `college` I need to modify it. But, i clearly didn't got the docs correctly and wasn't able to understand it well.

so I wanted to know whats the correct way of formatting the url?
[=> React-Places-Autocomplete docs](https://github.com/hibiken/react-places-autocomplete#searchoptions)

Answer (score 0):

Note that what you're using is Place Autocomplete, not Place Search. The supported types for Autocomplete are listed in [table 3](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3):

`geocode`
`address`
`establishment`
`(regions)`
`(cities)`

So using other types like `school` won't work with Autocomplete; only with the Place Search service.

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you suggest me how to edit this : `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
` and add restrictive parameter to it?

Comment: The thing is, you cannot. Your script is fine as it is. The only way to add Autocomplete restrictions is by modifying the `types` parameter to any of the values listed in my answer above. E.g.: `types: ['establishment']` (see https://github.com/hibiken/react-places-autocomplete#searchoptions and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete).